# Using Snowflake's Query_Tags in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, powerquery

We're trying to leverage Snowflake's query_tags within Power BI. This will allow us to drill into the overall costs by report/workspace. Has anyone been able to implement this? Seems like a logic addition.

When we try to add the following SQL to our reports and we're getting an error.

```
ALTER SESSION SET query_tag = 'Workspace - Report';
SELECT 
  *
FROM Some_view
```

[image]

We know that PBI doesn't like the semicolon at the end of the Alter session statement but removing it also throws a similar error.

The SQL runs without issue when removing the Alter Session statement.

Comment: What happens if you just run the ALTER without the SELECT?

Comment: If PBI doesn't like sending an `alter` statement, perhaps it would be okay with sending a `call` statement. You can set the query tag for a session in a stored procedure defined with `execute as caller`.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Assuming that a separate user is used from PowerBI to connect to Snowflake, the QUERY_TAG could be set up on the user level instead.

[QUERY_TAG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#query-tag)

> Type     Session — Can be set for Account » **User** » Session

For instance:

```
ALTER USER user_name_here SET query_tag = 'Workspace - Report';
```

Thus no need to alter session from Power BI.